# knowing if new record already exists

Tags: sql

i'm trying to check if the record i'm about to  insert on my table already exists but it must check 2 fields against a array...

i have a table with user and year, like this

```
john, 2002
john, 2003
john, 2004
```

and my insert statement is like this

```
foreach ($years as $value) {
$queryinsert = "INSERT INTO  payments VALUES ('$var1','$value')";
```

but the variable $years have this values(1999,2000,2001,2002,2003)

how can i make a check before i insert this values on the db if already have a user with that year
and report it in a msg like user John already paid for the year 2002, 2003!

Comment: can you use stored procedures?

Comment: You could also create a Unique constraint on the name and year columns, which would prevent duplicate rows being inserted.

Comment: Does your database product support the `MERGE` statement?

Comment: this is a online aplication and i'm using php and mysql...and i need to preform this check to prevent users to pay for the year twice.

Comment: i guess store procedures will be possible. Whats your idea Christos?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$queryinsert = "INSERT INTO payments (name,year)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$var1','$value') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name, year FROM payments WHERE name = '$var1' AND value='$value'
) LIMIT 1;"
```

I assume that the names of your columns are `name` and `year`. You should change them to that they actually are.

Comment: You need an `AND` in the WHERE clause of the sub query.